# Android Rootkit failed when hook sys_read about AT+CMGR

Tags: android, kernel, at-command, rootkit

I try to hook sys_call in Android 4.4.4 and the kernel version is 3.4.And I use LKM to do it.
First of all,I try to hook sys_write for getting send sms or dial behavior.Here's my hook sys_write code.

```
asmlinkage int hack_sys_write(unsigned int fd,char *buf,int count){

if(strstr(buf,"AT+CMGS")||strstr(buf,"ATD"))
{
  printk("buf is %s\n",k_buf);

 // the result is AT+CMGS=NUMBER(not tel number,just like 18,14..)

}
  return original_call_write(fd,buf,count);
}
```

Actually,I can capture the info when I send SMS or dial number,but I can't get the details about sms's content.(Intersting when I dial,the printk is ADT=Tel number,why...?)
 urm...then I try to hook sys_read to capture the info when I received SMS or phone,but the reult is null.Here is my hook sys_read code:

```
asmlinkage int hack_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char *buf, int count){
           if(strstr(buf,"AT+CLCC")||strstr(buf,"AT+CMGR"))
{
    printk("something is read aha %s\n", buf);

}
 return original_call_read(fd,buf,count);

}
```

The key word "AT+CLCC" or "AT+CMGR" can't be captured and the result is nothing.so,why I can't get info and how to solve it
?Plz help me,thanks.